# Spark (PySpark) File Already Exists Exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a data frame as a text file, however, I am getting a File Already Exists exception. I tried adding the mode to the code but to no avail. Furthermore, the file does not actually exists. Would anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem? I am using PySpark

This is the code:

```
distFile = sc.textFile("/Users/jeremy/Downloads/sample2.nq")
mapper = distFile.map(lambda q: __q2v(q))
reducer = mapper.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + os.linesep + b)
data_frame = reducer.toDF(["context", "triples"])
data_frame.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("context").text("/Users/jeremy/Desktop/so")
```

May I add that the exception is being raised after some time and that some data is actually stored in temporary files (which are obviously deleted).

Thanks!

Edit: Exception can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jerdeb/c30f65dc632fb997af289dac4d40c743

Answer (score 2):

you can used `overwrite` or `append` for replacing the file or adding the data into same file.

```
data_frame.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy("context").text("/Users/jeremy/Desktop/so")
```

or

```
data_frame.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').partitionBy("context").text("/Users/jeremy/Desktop/so")
```

Comment: I have uploaded the exception here: https://gist.github.com/jerdeb/c30f65dc632fb997af289dac4d40c743

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able get around it with this:

```
outputDir = "/FileStore/tables/my_result/"

dbutils.fs.rm(outputDir , True)
```

Just change the outputDir variable to whatever directory you are writing to.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your executors and look at the logs of the ones that are failing.

In my case, I had a `coalesce(1)` on a large DF. 4 of my executors failed - 3 of them had the same error of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: File already exists`.

However, 1 of them had a different exception: `org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 262144 bytes of memory, got 148328`

I was able to fix it by increasing the executor memory so that the coalesce did not cause an `out of memory` error.